# Is it possible to play sound on iOS simulator of Visual Studio 2017 Windows?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2017, ios-simulator

Can anyone please confirm whether possible to play sound on iOS simulator of Visual Studio 2017? Am currently implementing the Text to speech feature using AVSpeechSynthesizer. So I want to test speech from iOS simulator of VS 2017. So is it possible with VS simulator of windows or I can hear speech only from mac?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Audio on the macOS's is processed via the CoreAudio.framework (`coreaudiod`) for the `com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService` and is not forwarded to the "remote" iOS Simulator

Comment: @SushiHangover, Thanks for your info. So not possible to hear audio from remoted ios simulator and need to go mac for this.